# How many products do I have to create?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, products-management

I have 5 attributes. Each attributes has 16 values.

How many products I must create?

5x16 or 16x5x16 ?

Comment: are you want to create configurable products

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to create simple product or configurable product??

Comment: Configurable product. I thick is a setting of backend.

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on what the attributes mean and wether or not it is necessary to control the stock level on each of those.

***Example***

If i am selling t-shirts in 3 different colours and 2 different sizes and i wish to maintain a stock level for each combination then i must create a simple product for each (6 in all) and then put them in a configurable product.

Conversely, you may be someone who can make the t-shirts to order and do not need to worry about stock level. In that case you could just have a simple product with custom options.